# Animation stop with css3

Tags: css, animation

At the moment i am working on a header with a slider animation (css3 only):

http://jimmytenbrink.nl/slider/

Everything is working fine except sometimes the slider is bugging if you go from the center to the right. It seems that i need to stop the animation for a few miliseconds to complete. However i searched everywhere on the internet but i cant seem to get it to work.

Anyone here has experience with it who can help me out?

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <div><span>slide 1</span></div>
  <div><span>slide 2</span></div>
  <div><span>slide 3</span></div>
  <div><span>slide 4</span></div>
  <div><span>slide 5</span></div>
  <div><span>slide 6</span></div>
  <div><span>slide 7</span></div>
  <div><span>slide 8</span></div>    
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 500px;
}
header div {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 43.8px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: width .3s;
    transition: width .3s;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
header div:first-child {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
header div:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
header div:hover span {
    left: 50px;
    opacity: 1;
}
header div img {
    position: relative;
    left: -240px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    overflow:hidden;
}
header div span {
    -webkit-transition: left .3s;
    transition: left .3s;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    color: white;
    left: -350px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 450px;
    font-family:'Fugaz One', cursive;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #f1f1f1;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#f1f1f1, offx=0, offy=0);
}
header:hover > div {
    width: 43.8px;
}
header:hover > div:hover {
    width: 150px;
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cAn9X/)

So the question is, how can i set a stop on the animation for a few miliseconds so the animation can finish before it gets triggered again?

Hope my question is clear!

(thanks for the edit)

Comment: Did you try toggling with the `transition` attribute? Currently its `0.3s`. IF you increase it, you may get closer to what you need..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One might call my answer a *workaround*. Maybe it is but according to my comment on [ExtPro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19929117/1069604) - it is still completely pure CSS.
I decided to use `display: table-cell` since the table cell's width is distributed equally.

So, the CSS might look like this:
*HINT: This is only a bunch of necessary CSS. All the code is in the jsFiddle*

```
header {
    width: 368px;
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
}
header > div {
    width: 44px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: width .3s;
    transition: width .3s;
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
}
header > div:hover {
    width: 151px;
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cAn9X/8/)

As you can see, we don't have to determine the width of all *not-hovered* divs. Actually, the problem came from that very CSS rule:

```
/* DON'T USE THIS RULE - IT'S THE RULE WHICH WAS BAD */
header:hover > div {
    width: 43.8px;
}
```

You were changing the width of the divs on `header:hover`, so when the transition didn't manage to do its job in time, you came out with mouse pointing to the header but to **non** of the divs.

Comment: You'll have to make some minor modifications to get the solution working properly on your production site (images instead of spans, different widths etc.), but I think you have the big picture now.

Comment: Just made the modifications, you can check the new working version (thanks to you :D) here: 
http://jimmytenbrink.nl/slider/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you mean by 'bugging', what is happening is if you move the mouse quickly to the right, it traverses the currently open div and is left in an area which when that div collapses, does not contain (e.g. the mouse is not hovered over) the next one in order to expand it- namely the hover event of the following div(s) is/are not firing thus they do not expand. There wont be a CSS fix for this Im afraid as its browser related, you may want to replace with jQuery/JS.

Comment: I can't agree with you. Right now I'm preparing a working pure CSS solution.